# getlaunchintentforpackage returning null

Tags: android, android-package-managers

Can someone tell me please why this gives me *null* on the variable `intent`?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static String action = "com.google.android.youtube";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        this.launch();
    }

    public void launch() {
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(action);
        System.out.println("debug: " + intent);
        //startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

i test this on a pixel 4 and i never do uninstall youtube. also, sidequest list the app and gives me the package *com.google.android.youtube*

Comment: Is your Pixel 4 updated to Android 11? If so, you might be being caught by https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/package-visibility.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thats it. On a Android 10 device I do not have this problem. So now I know what to do for Android 11. Thank you

Comment: @CommonsWare I have been dealing with this issue for days. It has driven me mad why my intent was always `null`. Thanks for the link. Would you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 10):

For many (perhaps most) `PackageManager` methods, on Android 11 and higher, you need to take into account [package visibility rules](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility) and [add a `<queries>` element to your manifest](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/declaring) to declare what third-party apps you are interest in discovering or analyzing.

Comment: <queries> elements Fixed for me . thanks!

Comment: It is not working for me please help me

Answer (score 1):

Add below code in manifiest at below level hope it will work with you.

```
<manifest
    <application
            >
        </application>

        <queries>
        <intent>
         <action android:name="com.google.android.youtube.api.service.START"/>
        </intent>
        </queries>
    </manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the package name of the app you want to launch at build-time, then see CommonsWare's answer, as this will work on Android 11+. For my case I don't know the package name at build-time because we get it from a server call, so I can't put that in my manifest. I had to take a different approach.

If you know the activity name of the package you are trying to launch, you don't **need** to call `getLaunchIntentForPackage`, as you can replicate its behaviour yourself. If you [look at the source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/ApplicationPackageManager.java) for `getLaunchIntentForPackage`, the `PackageManager` is used only to get the activity class name for the package being launched.

So here's my re-implementation which works on Android 11+ if you already know the activity class name:

```
// you have String variables packageName and className (fully-qualified)
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
intent.setPackage(packageName);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setClassName(packageName, className);
startActivity(intent);
```

---

PS: If you do know the app package name, but don't know the activity name, probably the best way to get the activity name is just to run `getLaunchIntentForPackage` on an earlier version of Android (version 10 or below) where that app is installed, and get the activity name from the resulting intent (`intent.getComponent().getClassName()`).

For example, for YouTube the values would be:

- `packageName = "com.google.android.youtube"`
- `className = "com.google.android.youtube.app.honeycomb.Shell$HomeActivity"`